# Is there such a thing as Eternal Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

Since transplanting a relative's Mangekyou Sharingan gets you an Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan, will transplanting a regular Sharingan get you an Eternal Sharingan?

Answer (score 2):

The Mangekyou Sharingan is an eye that makes you gradually go blind when after a long periods of use. The Sharingan does not have this side effect. Therefore, the "Eternal" part of the Sharingan, which denotes an eye that will not get progressively blinder overtime, does not apply to a normal Sharingan.

In fact, the only real benefit to transplanting a normal Sharingan (given that you already have one) is so that you can use the [Izanagi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanagi). This technique makes the eye lose its light in one go.

> It can be seen during Obito's fight with Konan, that he transplanted an eye which he then used for the purpose of reviving himself with the Izanagi

Comment: Not only the Izanagi, the person can use the Izanami too.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin This is true, but you don't need another eye to use the Izanami. It seems like it would be the case, since it's the counter to the Izanagi, you can use the Izanami without loss of eyesight.

Comment: Sorry but that isn't the case. During the Kabuto-Uchiha brothers confrontation, Edo Tensei Itachi uses Izanami. And we see that his eye becomes disabled. The price is same for both techniques, but the process and the outcome differs.